# get ID at time of insert / replicate value into other

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to get the ID of what the entry in the MySQL DB is going to be ?
Or even better replicate the value of ID into another field ?
For example I have:

`ID` and `User_ID` and I want them always to be the same value

```
--------------------
|  ID   User_ID    |
|  1       1       |
|  2       2       |
|  3       3       |
|  4       4       |
|  5       5       |
--------------------
```

And so on

Comment: ID and User_ID and I want them always to be the same value <- Worst. Idea. Ever. Anyway, use triggers. My work here is done. (let me expand this into an answer, i'm feeling nice)

Comment: sounds like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find your need quite questionable, and a design smell. Nevertheless, you have the chance to achieve what you're looking for. The key is a **trigger**.

here you can find **[TRIGGER SYNTAX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)**

Basically you need to define a proper **AFTER INSERT** trigger.

Insert the row without the user_id field set, read the autoincrement id inside the trigger and set the user_id value as needed.

I'm not going to post an example because the manual is quite exaustive and it's a good read anyway.

Why I think that your idea is bad? well, you're duplicating data (by your very definition, "you want them always to be the same") without gaining value. The duplicate column is completely useless by all rights, and can be removed. If you're using them as a key or foreign key reference, the two column are completely interchangeable. Therefore, simply drop one of them and be done with it.

Comment: Mind explaining your earlier comment `Worst. Idea. Ever.` It's not much of help if you just flag this as bad, but don't point out why it is ?

Comment: If you have 2 columns that contain exactly the same data, what's the point of it? That's why it's worst idea ever and I happen to agree. +1 here.

Comment: Thank you :).. going to drop User_ID then.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_insert_id()` after calling your `mysql_query`

Or `mysqli_insert_id()` is using mysqli_ instead of just mysql_

More information here https://www.php.net/mysql_insert_id note that all the `mysql_` functions are now depreciated, so I would suggest mysqli_ or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`name`) VALUES ('name')")){
  $id = (int)mysql_insert_id();
  mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `User_ID` = {$id}");
}
```

But this is not good idea from the beginning :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using auto increment, then what you want is inside:

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name = 'myTable' AND table_schema = DATABASE( )
```

so in that case use for example:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (ID, User_ID) values ( NULL ,
    (
        SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.tables
        WHERE table_name = 'myTable' AND table_schema = DATABASE( )
    )
);
```

The Null indicates an auto increment ID. And the subquery will yield the auto increment ID to be used.

If you are not using auto increment, then you can simply do:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (ID, User_ID) values ( 5 , ID );
```

... and thus referencing ID to User_ID

Comment: RE: your last query: why not directly write `INSERT INTO myTable (ID, User_ID) values ( 5 , 5 );` then?

Comment: @sttlcu I didnt write the question ;). I wouldn't even know the point of having a second column containing the same data. But it could avoid having to set/send the same parameter twice.